# Evaluating $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n}$$

I'm working on a proof that, if I could show the previous expression evaluates to zero could be helpful, but I'm really doubtful about it. It must have been talked about before on this site I just haven't been able to find it.

I know that the sum of the harmonic series diverges and the limit of $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N}=0$, so it comes down to a zero times infinity situation.

Comment: Use the Stolz's theorem. The answer is $0$.

Comment: In general, if $a_n\to L$ then $\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n}\to L$. Your sequence is the sequence of means of $\frac{1}{n}$, so it converges to $0$.

Comment: One other approach is via the harmonic series asymptotics $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = \log(n) + \gamma + \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n})$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I am not seeing quite how to apply the Stolz-Cesàro theorem. It looks like we need an expression of this form: $\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n{b_{n+1}-b_n}$, and prove first that this limit exists. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, of course. Also, we need that $n$ would be increasing, which happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to do this directly and without integration, consider

for an upper bound:
$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{N}\cdot\big( \sum_{n=1}^{N} 1\cdot\frac{1}{n}\big)\leq \frac{1}{N}\cdot \big(N\big)^\frac{1}{2} \big(\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^2}\big)^\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\cdot \big(\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^2}\big)^\frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{C}{\sqrt{N}}$
for some constant $C$, where the first inequality is Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Wow this one really speaks to me. I knew when you brought that $1$ out you were up to something sneaky.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

You have a Riemann sum:
$$\sum_{n=2}^N\frac 1n<\int_1^N\frac{\mathrm dt}t=\ln(N),\quad\text{
so}\quad\displaystyle\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n}\le\frac1N+\frac{\ln(N)}{N}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Find a simple upper bound of the integral of $\int_1^N \frac1x\,dx$ to show that $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1n\le \log(N)+1$.

Comment: I see, I guess the thing I am missing is the connection between the series and the integral. Do we just say that $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n} < \int_1^N \frac{1}{x} dx$ as a general rule because the integral is smoother so it fills in the area between the steps left by the summation?

Comment: No, we compare $1/x$ on an interval $[n,n+1]$ to its maximum or minimum there.  Since $1/x$ is decreasing, this is easy.  But this shows an upper bound for $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n}$ is $\int_1^{N+1}\frac{1}{x}\;dx$.  This still is plenty to solve the OP.

Comment: @gedgar $\log(N+1)$ is not an upper bound for $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1n$.  However, for a monotonically decreasing function $f$, we have the estimate (i.e., upper bound) $$\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)\le f(1) +\int_1^N f(x)\,dx$$

Answer (score 2):

If you are aware of harmonic numbers
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n}=H_N$$ For large $N$, we have
$$H_N=\gamma +\log \left({N}\right)+\frac{1}{2N}+O\left(\frac{1}{N^2}\right)$$
$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n}=\frac{H_N}{N}=\frac \gamma  N+\frac {\log \left({N}\right)} N+\frac{1}{2N^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{N^3}\right)\sim \frac \gamma  N$$
Just by curiosity, compute for $N=10$; the exact value is $\frac{7381}{25200}\approx 0.292897$ while the truncated expansion would give $\frac{\gamma }{10}+\frac{\log (10)}{10}+\frac{1}{200}\approx 0.292980$.